# What is a flag in programming Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05

I have seen many tutorials on programming an Arduino to control a HC-05 bluetooth module. In that I did not understand the term called 'flag'. What does that mean?

Comment: And what is the context of this word?

Comment: "Flag" is usually a feature that you can turn on or off. The "flag" is the variable that you need to use to do that. But as Majenko stated, with no context, it's just a guess I am taking here.

Answer (score 4):

I've always used flag to indicate a boolean logic value. I would also suggest this is an archaic term.

Was going to come up with my own explanation but found the following at [In C language, what does flag mean?](https://www.quora.com/In-C-language-what-does-flag-mean-Is-it-an-arbitrary-variable-name-Can-I-use-flag-2-or-b-etc):

> A 'flag' is a variable that is supposed to signalize something. Think
>   about the word itself - flags are used in sending signals. In our
>   world of programming a basic boolean flag can either be "up" or
>   "down", either true or false.